# spring's callable anonymous inner class not getting executed

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/helloAsync")
public Callable<String> sayHelloAsync() {
    // logger.info("Entering controller");
    System.out.println("Entering  controller ---------------------> ");
    System.out.println("1");
    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(" hurray !!!! ------------------------->");
            return billSheduleService.doSlowWork();             
        }
    };
}
```

here when I call this controller method all `println()` are printed except the ones in callable's `call()` i.e. callable inner class is not executing.

I am using spring version 3.2.5.

Comment: What happens in terms of the response? Is `doSlowWork()` being called and returning a value? I'm wondering whether this is actually an artifact of diagnostic differences (where the output of `System.out.println` goes) rather than a matter of it not being called.

Comment: Can you show me your web.xml ? You should have async servlets turned on (only in Servlet API 3.x+) by having something like this in web.xml: <async-supported>true</async-supported>